# why is a Lagrangian submanifold a semi-classical state and not a classical state?

Tags: mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-formalism, semiclassical

I read that the Lagrangian submanifold can be regarded as a semi-classical state when classical mechanics is formulated using symplectic geometry. Does anyone know why it would be a semi-classical state instead of a classical state?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.4847 for instance.

Comment: To answer this question, what is your definition of semi-classical vs. classical states?

Comment: A semi-classical state is a solution to the Schroedinger equation in first order of $\hbar$, a classical state is obtained in the limit $\hbar$ goes to zero.

Comment: Then in your terminology, the authors mean classical state rather than semiclassical state.

Comment: Ah! Alright, thanks very much! So what terminology do they use such that they explicitly mention semi-classical instead of classical?